# How to export / saveas TikZ as DXF files?

Tags: tikz-pgf, export

In python, there are very good packages to produce DXF format drawings (eg [ezDXF](https://ezdxf.mozman.at/docs/)). DXF can be easily imported to any CAD software. Are there any similar packages to export a TikZ drawing to DXF format? At least for 2D simple drawings.

Comment: google suggests several svg to dxf convertors eg https://convertio.co/svg-dxf/ but  have no idea if they work

Comment: Personally I use dvisvgm to compile to svg and then convert the svg to dxf with inkscape.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz seems most of existing tools use online sites and apis or inkscape. No good python, lua or tex package to do this directly in the code. And none of the web backends are open-source!